# How to execute U-SQL Stored Procedure In ADLA from Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, u-sql, azure-data-factory

How can I execute a U-SQL stored procedure in ADLA  from Azure Data Factory?
As of now, I could see that U-SQL activity looks for U-SQL script and it's location.

Likewise 'Stored Procedure' activity wherein any RDBMS stored procedures can be executed, I just need to invoke U-SQL stored procedure, without any wrapper scripts.

Am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U-SQL Stored Procedures can only be executed from a U-SQL script, so you would still need to wrap the call in a U-SQL script and reference the wrapper script in your ADF activity.

Comment: I agree. It would have been better without wrapper scripts.,even though it's a wrapper but needs additional maintenance. Thanks for confirming.